# How do I compile a .dll by hand using csc.exe that has a Fakes Assembly reference?

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes, csc

Here's my file/folder structure:

```
 \
 |
 --RealLibrary\
 |  |
 |  --RealClass.cs
 |
 --SandboxFakesByHand\
    |
    --Fakes\
    |  |
    |  --RealLibrary.fakes
    |
    --Consumer.cs
```

The contents of **RealClass.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RealLibrary
{
    public class RealClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The contents of **Consumer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SandboxFakesByHand
{
    public class Consumer
    {
        public static void Method()
        {
            var a = new RealLibrary.Fakes.ShimRealClass();
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of **RealLibrary.fakes**

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="RealLibrary"/>
</Fakes>
```

Here's what I tried from the Developer Command Prompt for VS2012 (Premium) (starting in `\RealLibrary\`):

```
> csc /target:library RealClass.cs
> cd ..\SandboxFakesByHand
> csc /target:library Consumer.cs
```

The last one gives me an error of:

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.33440
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Consumer.cs(13,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RealLibrary' could
        not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
        reference?)
```

**What I need to do to compile the Consume.cs file by hand?**

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a reference to your `csc` line:

```
csc /target:library /reference:..\RealLibrary\RealClass.dll Consumer.cs
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That actually doesn't solve my issue as it doesn't generate the fakes assembly.  Have you heard of Microsoft fakes before?

Comment: @WordsLikeJared: I'm somewhat familiar with Fakes, yes. I didn't read your question well enough, however, I understood it as your problem being the compilation of the test after generating the fakes assembly. I haven't compiled fakes by hand myself and my current employer doesn't have a license so I can't test now, but this article (http://csharpening.net/?p=1381) should cover the necessary incantations (some powershell translation needed, though).
Hope that helps, sorry about the confusion.